# Getting Cursor To Show Up On Input Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any thoughts on best approach to be able to focus on an input and be able to get the cursor to show up in the input?

Edit: Solution had been to use focus() but also make sure I had only one element with the id I had been selecting for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery has a function for this .focus

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0ceqkwv3/

```
$('#idOfInput').focus()
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your response @Rick, are there any requirements for that to work other than jQuery and an input with an id of 'idOfInput' on the page?

I have a page that seemingly meets those requirements but .focus() is not working with

Comment: Nope just query and the idOfInput is just whatever the id, it doesn't matter what it is, as you can see on my Fiddle that calls for the id of foo

Comment: If it isn't working it can be a few things, a js error on the page, or possibly two inputs with the same ID. Right click in Chrome and choose inspect element, see if there are any errors. One other possibility is if you are running your script before you import jQuery.

Comment: Two elements with the same id, that was it, thanks a ton man.

Comment: :) glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

To focus an element with JQuery : https://api.jquery.com/focus/